# Django served bootstrap.js file not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

Edit: So I've narrowed the problem down - it works when I link to an externally hosted bootstrap.min.js file, and doesn't work when I use the local file (django's dev static folder setup)

This has me pulling my hair out. I've looked at tons of threads, inspected the HTML very carefully, and I can't tell what's the difference. Here's my dev page: http://iceberg.creatifcubed.com:8080, and here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5UAUP/4/

The problem is on a mobile browser (iPhone and iPad) the login dropdown closes when I click on it. Many threads recommended `e.stopPropagation()` - which is showing up in a desktop browser but not on the mobile browser. I added some alerts, and tried different variations to attach the event - and it's not being called in mobile safari.

I add the same code into jsfiddle - and it works there (copied and pasted the same HTML - see jsfiddle /5UAUP/5). Don't even need `e.stopPropagation()`. I ran my code through the w3 validator and there are no errors. Any idea what could be causing this?

Currently, my page is set to use the local static file. It's been included properly and everything - you can see it at http://iceberg.creatifcubed.com:8080/static/lib/bootstrap-2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js . I've checked the headers, and I don't see anything strange - so why does it cause that javascript bug when I link to the local file? Other parts of the file - like the carousel plugin - seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually a bug in 2.3.2. Github issue: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/7927

Just the way I tested 2.3.0, 2.3.1, and 2.3.2 with serving from Django vs. CDN and accidentally caching just happened to not show me it was nothing to do with django until after asking this question >.<

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually much easier than you'd think and it's unfortunate that people have to waste time on this little quirk, but I promise now that you know it, you'll never forget it!

```
$('.dropdown form').on('click tap', function (e) {
```

All you have to do is add a "tap" handler, so that mobile browsers react to it properly. By the way, this DOES work because jquery will automatically split up event handlers by spaces, so "click" and "tap" are two distinct handlers

Comment: Hmmm, I tried it here no luck :/ http://jsfiddle.net/5UAUP/13/ I actually found it to be a bug between 2.3.1 and 2.3.2... argh, I tried 2.3.0 and 2.3.2 I'm pretty sure it didn't work in 2.3.0 (It definitely doesn't in 2.3.2)